# Are the norms for cordless screwdriver charging stations?

Tags: battery, screwdriver

So I found this cordless screwdriver at my house but there is no charger for it so I would like to buy a used one for it (it's very cheap so I also don't want to spend a lot of money to buy a new one). I also have another cordless screwdriver at home and I just tested to see if the battery from the first cordless screwdriver fits in its charging station and apparently it does. It seems that many of these cheap cordless screwdrivers conform to a certain standard ( regarding the size and shape of the plugs and sockets), but I can't find any information about it. I would like to buy a used charger on ebay, but I want to avoid the situation where I think it fits my cordless screwdriver when in reality it does not (then I would end up with having bought a charger which I cannot use).

I guess from the information on the battery I have to stick to a 18V charging station but maybe there's also a way to also search specifically for the shape of the charging station I need?

Here are some pictures:

[image]

Comment: What's the brand name on the screwdriver?

Comment: What made you think it would be a good idea to black out the name in your pics?

Comment: What is the voltage **and battery type** of the charging station it "appears to fit?"

Comment: The brandname of the screwdriver is **CMI** and the charging station's name is **SKIL**. I didn't know if it's okay to post the brands' names that's why I blacked them out. @Ecnerwal: I don't know, unfortunately. On the screwdriver's akku it says Cd 18V

Comment: There's NO cross-manufacturer standard, *especially* between respectable brands and the cheap Cheese junk.  The information on the equipment's labeling is absolutely essential.

Answer (score 3):

> I found this cordless screwdriver at my house

So, it's about 99% likely to be junk, battery that no longer works, not worth any investment in parts to fit it.

Why? Well, **it was abandoned**, and it's apparently some off-brand. These things are made to get sold once, and mostly last to the end of a short warranty or the changing of the name of the company, whichever comes first, and then die.

Why, part 2: - it's a **NiCd battery**. Not NiMh (*somewhat* more up to date, *somewhat* less prone to swift death) nor Li-ion (modern, decent portable tool, phone, computer batteries, tend to work well and last a long time.) NiCd battery tools (when they were the best thing you could get, battery-wise) were quickly eclipsed in price by the replacement batteries they needed, over, and over, and over again, because NiCd batteries are not fond of real-world rechargeable use, and tend to die in short order. That included NiCd battery tools from "quality" brands, though they did last longer than the ones from off-brands.

When it comes to tools, being cheap over and over is expensive, while buying quality once averages out to be inexpensive.

Comment: I think first of all it's always good to save electronic devices if you can.  I didn't buy the screwdriver, I found it and want to give it a second chance. That's why I also would only buy a used charging station for it in order to stick to the goal to use electronic devices that are already there. Flagged your answer because you were commenting on my behavior instead of providing a focused answer to the question (at least in your first part)

Comment: Many electronic devices are better recycled than "saved."  That's practical advice relevant to your question, which you can ignore if you like wasting money and planetary resources throwing good after bad.

Comment: Johannes, in my humble opinion the only battery operated tools worth buying are those from RIDGID, and only from Home Depot, and only if you CAREFULLY follow all of the requirements in the lifetime warranty for registration.  This is because their lifetime warranty covers battery replacement.  Rechargeable tool batteries have a very short life compared to the actual life of the tool itself.  I have AC power cord tools that are older than you are which are still in service.  You might also consider not boasting about flagging someone if you want further answers.

Comment: Short battery life is far less true from quality name brands with Li-ion battery tech. And HomelyDespot is not worldwide. I have an old (at the time, good) NiCd/NIMh Bosch that's not worth buying batteries for, but which I have not yet thrown out since it could conceivably be adapted to car battery short-cord power (it's 12V.) But the 18V Ryobi that replaced it is still doing quite well on the first two Li-ion batteries that came with it, and it's been enough years now that I don't recall how many years it's been. I have not needed replacement batteries yet.